# Blazor for Web, Blazor .NET MAUI for cross platform or Blazor Hybrid for Web and cross platform

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I would like to build a website and also an app that can be shipped in Android and iOS.

I searched in internet, and found there are multiple options for me to choose:

- Blazor which only for website
- Blazor .NET MAUI which only for Android and iOS
- Blazor Hybrid

Should I create 2 different projects, which Blazor and Blazor with .NET MAUI or I should create Blazor Hybrid which can cater website and also Android and iOS?

If Blazor Hybrid can cater all those things, how do I create one?

What I am using currently is only Blazor for website

Answer (score 1):

You can create a .NET MAUI application with Blazor support, by creating a project with the template called ".NET MAUI Blazor App":

[image]

This will allow you to create both a Blazor application and a native app and share different components between them. The problem with this approach is that you need to maintain two separate codebases. You also need to consider during development with code you must put in which project. If possible, I recommend you using a different framework that both supports web and native apps. One such framework that uses C# and XAML is "Uno Platform". If you really have to go the Blazor and MAUI hybrid, then I recommend you reading the following blog post: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/blazor-dotnet-maui-what-how-when